# gwt decorated tab panel not showing the tabs properly

Tags: gwt

I have create a DecoratedTabPanel in GWT

```
 <g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="hpnlTab">
            <g:DecoratedTabPanel animationEnabled="true" ui:field="tabQuran" width="499px" height="281px">
                <g:Tab text="Quran">
                    <g:HTMLPanel width="249px" height="262px" ui:field="quranTab">
                    <!--  <div class="{style.qFrameMiddle}" id="middleFrame">-->
            <div  ui:field="quranText" class="{style.quranText}">       

            </div> 

        </g:HTMLPanel>
                </g:Tab>
                <g:Tab text="Translation">
                    <g:HTMLPanel width="7cm" height="249px"/>
                </g:Tab>
            </g:DecoratedTabPanel>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Its working fine , showing the word Testing, when i click on testing, its also opens the HtmlPanel , but the problem is , its not showing TABS, just a simple text, see the image

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in your ModuleName.gwt.xml has inherited standard theme or another one:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
```

Or you are somewhere overriding its default styles.